Excel - creating a chart using column data as x axis labels - how to set date intervals to yearly, rather than daily?
I am trying to create a simple line chart in Excel, using the data such as the following:

However, when inserting the graph using this data, the X axis is labelled with daily intervals, rather than yearly, which is the data I have used (the first column in the table), giving me a graph such as:

How can I get the X axis to plot the points on the annual basis as per the data in the first column, rather than on a daily basis, which it seems to be doing at the moment?
Edit in response to answer:
I removed the first column, and added it back as the Horizontal Axis labels, but for some reason, it only displays the first cell's data:

When I right-click on the x axis, and choose Select Data, for some reason, the data selected only gives the contents of the first cell in the selection, and the rest appear blank:


Check which data is used as x-axis, it seems to be the wrong data set (series 1 being the years you actually want).

If I am not mistaken, your chart should be like this:


Presently the Series 1 shows under legend entries as per your screenshot it needs to be removed and needs to placed under Horizontal Axis lables, like the one I have shown.

For doing this select the chart, From Chart Design Ribbon Tab --> Click on Select Data.
Select Series 1 which is Column A and Remove.
Now, select Edit under Horizontal Axis Lables and select the range from Column A and press OK Twice. You will see the desired output.


Also, in order to make the Chart Dynamic I will define the series name using a dynamic formula and use it within the Chart for Legend and Horizontal axis. Please refer the screenshot 2nd one.


• For Years:
=$A$1:INDEX($A$1:$A$7,COUNT($A$1:$A$7))


• For Series 2:
=$B$1:INDEX($B$1:$B$7,COUNT($B$1:$B$7))


• For Series 3:
=$C$1:INDEX($C$1:$C$7,COUNT($C$1:$C$7))



Thanks for your answer. I gave what you suggested a go, but after removing series 1 (the years), and selecting them as the Horizontal Axis Labels, I only get the first cell displayed in the horizontal axis - not sure why this is... Will update my OP to show it now.

You shouldn;t be getting the first cell only unless you are not selecting the whole range. Not sure what you did

@Noble-Surfer are you using Pivot Tables? And do you have empty cells in between ? Your initial screenshot shows only years, please post your actual source data

No, I'm not using Pivot tables, and although the data was originally populated in this table using a number of VLOOKUPs to copy it from elsewhere in the workbook, I have copied and used 'paste special' to paste the values looked up over the top of the formulae, so these cells now only contain the values, not the formulae. There are no blank cells between years.

I am selecting the whole range - click the first one, then CTRL+SHIFT+Down to select all populated cells below it.

But its unclear, there is something in your data source which we dont see. Will you be able to post the excel?

The first cell in the Dates column contains "N/A" (as this was the value based on the formula in the cell the vlookup took it from), however, none of the cells in the Dates column contain any formulae any more, as I've used 'paste special' to paste the values in over the top of the formulae which had looked them up. I excluded the first cell from the list when selecting the labels for the x axis, to see if this made a difference, but it doesn't appear to.

The two other columns used to plot the graph, i.e. the ones plotting the lines do contain formulae - the first a  countif, and the second a simple a+b. However, these columns which do have formulae are being used correctly by the graph - otherwise, the lines wouldn't be plotted.

Ah, it seems the issue must have been that I was using CTRL+Shift+Down to select the range - if I click and drag using the cursor, it seems to select the range correctly... not sure why that is!

@Noble-Surfer that is why I have suggested a dynamic solution using defined names. It will be dynamic, you dont have to worry for the range.
